# Win32 window not redrawing when controls are updated

Tags: c++, winapi

I am new to win32 programming, so I apologize in advance. I have a window with 2 problems that seem related.

1. if I resize a window, it leaves a portion of the background black, or all of it if I minimize.
2. I have a `SysLink` that when clicked calls `ShowWindow` to hide itself and shows a hidden combobox control. The combobox displays, but the link doesn't hide. It is inaccessible, but still visible.

[image]

The following is the full test code.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <commctrl.h>

#pragma comment(linker,"\"/manifestdependency:type='win32' \
name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' \
processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
HWND link;
HWND combo;

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, 
                    PWSTR pCmdLine,
                    int CmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSW wc = {0};
    wc.lpszClassName = L"MainWindow";
    wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
    wc.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;
    wc.hCursor       = LoadCursor(0, IDC_ARROW);

    RegisterClassW(&wc);
    CreateWindowW(wc.lpszClassName, L"Test", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE,
                  0, 0, 340, 280,
                  nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);
    
    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return (int)msg.wParam;
} // end wWinMain

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
        case WM_CREATE:
            link = CreateWindowExW(0, L"SysLink", L"<a>Add filter</a>",
                                   WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
                                   20, 20, 100, 28, hwnd, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);
            combo = CreateWindowExW(0, L"COMBOBOX", nullptr,
                                    WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | CBS_DROPDOWNLIST | CBS_HASSTRINGS,
                                    50, 20, 140, 28, hwnd, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);
            ShowWindow(combo, SW_HIDE);
            break;

        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            return 0;

        case WM_NOTIFY:
            switch (((LPNMHDR)lParam)->code)
            {
                case NM_CLICK:
                case NM_RETURN:
                    if (((LPNMHDR)lParam)->hwndFrom == link)
                    {
                        ShowWindow(link, SW_HIDE);
                        ShowWindow(combo, SW_SHOW);
                    }
                    break;
            }
    }

    return DefWindowProcW(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The window class is registered without a background brush. To fix that, and the repaint along with it, add (for example) the following before `RegisterClassW`.

```
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
```

Comment: @PaulSanders Thanks for catching that, fixed now. For reference, the `+1` is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-wndclassw).

Comment: Thank you, I am very frustrated at how simple a fix this was. I must have missed that line in the demo I was using

Comment: @steveo225 Now you'll know it when you see it next time. Thing is that working at the C WinAPI level is not too forgiving.

Comment: Oh trust me, I know already. The number of things I have had to force through myself already has been insane. I am trying to limit my SO questions to problems I am stuck on for multiple days. I usually use Qt or some graphics toolkit, but wanted a stab at native GUI programming. It is hard, but it uses so much less memory and is generally much more responsive. Win some, lose some